# Azure Function giving error on start Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.pdb not loaded

Tags: azure-functions

i am using Azure functions with the following packages

[image]

on startup it is erroring out. Any idea how to debug this error ?
[image]

i suspect something is happening in startup. here is my startup file

```
    using eReserveIntegration.DataAccess;
using eReserveIntegration.DataAccess.Contracts;
using eReserveIntegration.Services;
using eReserveIntegration.Services.Contracts;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureAppConfiguration;
using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets;
using eReserveIntegration.Models;

[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(eReserveIntegration.Functions.Startup))]
namespace eReserveIntegration.Functions
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        private static IConfiguration _config;
        private static IConfigurationRefresher _refresher;
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {

            ConfigureServices(builder.Services);


        }

        private void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var credentialOptions = new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions
            {
                ManagedIdentityClientId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_CLIENT_ID"),

            };

            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            builder.AddAzureAppConfiguration(o =>
            {
                o.Connect(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AppConfigConString"))
                 .ConfigureRefresh(ro =>
                    ro.Register("Sentinel", LabelFilter.Null, refreshAll: true)
                      .SetCacheExpiration(TimeSpan.FromDays(99999)))
                 .ConfigureKeyVault(kv =>
                 {
                     kv.SetCredential(new DefaultAzureCredential());
                 });
                _refresher = o.GetRefresher();
            });
            _config = builder.Build();


           // await _refresher.Refresh();
            services.Configure<EReserveFunctions>(_config.GetSection("EReserveFunctions"));

            services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(
       Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ApplicationInsights:InstrumentationKey"));
            services.AddScoped<IDataService, DataService>();
            services.AddScoped<ITransformationService, TransformationService>();
            services.AddScoped<IMappingService, MappingService>();
            services.AddScoped<IExtractionService, ExtractionService>();
            services.AddScoped<IRepository, SQLRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IHelperService, HelperService>();
            services.AddScoped<IDALSession, DALSession>();
            services.AddScoped<ITraceService, TraceService>();
            services.AddScoped<IOverrideService, OverrideService>();
            services.AddScoped<IOnDemandService, OnDemandService>();
            services.AddScoped<ICalculationsService, CalculationsService> 
         ();
        }
    }
}
```

when all the connection strings and keys seems to be picked up correctly. 
problem is i cannot figure out the source of the error.

Comment: For null reference it should be easy to solve without debugging given line number. Try using (myobj ?? new object()).someprop or similar.

Comment: problem is its not telling me which file and code area its giving error on

Comment: Can remove the Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore NuGet package and try again, please? I'm just wondering what it's going to say.

Comment: by just removing that it just worked.  and i am using insights telemetry it is not erroring out. so i am wondering how does it knows which insights to talk to.

Comment: Great! Out-of-the-box IServiceCollection has a method .AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(). So you don't have to add .AspNetCore NuGet package. When you add the second NuGet package, it basically conflicts :) Don't forget to upvote my comment mate :))) Cheers @RaasMasood